# Gravity forms submit to third party and redirect using wp_http()

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to get a gravity form from my wordpress website to serve as a login form for another application (CakePhp website). The form has two fields-username and password. I have added a hook to submit the form to the other application using gform_after_submission as follows:

```
    add_action( 'gform_after_submission_6', 'mysite_gform_after_submission', 10, 2 ); 

    function mysite_gform_after_submission( $entry, $form ) {

     $post_url = 'http://otherapplicationurl.com/login';

     $body = array(
            "data[User][username]" => $entry[1], 
            "data[User][password]" => $entry[2], 
     );

        $request = new WP_Http();
        $response = $request->post($post_url, array('body' => $body));
    //this is to delete the entry

    GFAPI::delete_entry( $entry['id'] );
    }
```

The form's confirmation setting is to display some text. But what I essentially want it to do is login the user to the other application and show the homepage of that application i.e redirect to the url "http://otherapplicationurl.com/home".

I keep getting the following error.

```
    WP_Error Object
    (
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [http_request_failed] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Too many redirects.
                    )

            )

        [error_data] => Array()

    )
```

I don't know how to get the form to log the user in and redirect to the other applications home page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You've hit a very tricky process here. What you're trying to do is two things simultaneously:

1. Log in to an external service
2. Redirect to the user to the service

Technically, this can't be done the way you're looking to do it. And here's why:

**You're dealing with cookies.** When you log in, data is stored as a cookie/session that will remember who you are as you navigate through the site. The info is also only available to the relevant domain/path, and can only be set from that same domain/path.

**The server, not the user, is logging in.**
In other words, you're trying to log the user into the service from another domain via the server. In this case, the server will log in on behalf of the user (as it's the server doing the request), but will do nothing with the cookies. Even if we sent the cookies back to the user, they would apply under the original domain and we'd be no closer to being logged in.

**Solution 1: Simple, but insecure**

What you could do, is make the redirect and the login process the same thing. That is, using a URL such as http://otherapplication.com/login?user=adomnom&pass=awesome (though I *strongly* discourage that for security reasons).

**Solution 2: Secure, but (you guessed it) complex**

A safer approach would be to use the structure you have at the moment to generate a one-time login code. That is, the server will request a unique, one-time 'token' from the other application using the login details and use these as part of the redirect. The user is taken to this other page and is logged in using this token as a substitute for credentials. After this, the token should then become invalid.

That way, the other application is the one setting the cookies and no sensitive information is being directly transferred.

And here's how I'd do it...

**1. Create new endpoint on the CakePHP side: /get-token**

This endpoint will receive the username and password from GET data, then generate, store and return a unique token.

**2. Extend /login on the CakePHP side to allow for a 'token' GET variable**

Submitting 'token' to /login should also log in the user and delete the token - preventing it from being used again.

**3. Update the submission process to use the correct hook**

You'll want to use the **[gform_confirmation](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/gravity-forms/extending-gravity-forms/hooks/filters/gform_confirmation/)** hook to do this - it's the hook that deals with redirects and thank you page contents (ie. the stuff that the user is shown after submitting the form).

```
add_action( 'gform_confirmation_6', 'mysite_gform_confirmation', 10, 3 ); 

function mysite_gform_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $entry ) {

    // Send login request
    $token = wp_remote_post(
        'http://otherapplicationurl.com/login',
        array(
            'body' => array(
                "data[User][username]" => $entry[1], 
                "data[User][password]" => $entry[2]
            )
        )
    );

    // Delete entry
    GFAPI::delete_entry( $entry['id'] );

    // Redirect
    return array('redirect', "http://otherapplicationurl.com/login?token=$token");
}
```

Hope that helps! Good luck!